# Error de conexión en Apps Script - TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSheetByName' of null

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo, bootstrap-5

Tratando de hacer un formulario en **Apps Script**, da el error:

> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSheetByName' of null (línea 20,
> archivo "Código")"

En el documento **Código.gs**, esa línea es la tercera:

```
function doPost( e ){
var SS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheetRegistro = SS.getSheetByName('Registro');
```

Tengo una carpeta en GDrive, y ahí el fichero de Apps Script y otro una Google Sheet llamada **Registro**.

Creo que el problema es que no se vinculan, pero aunque probablemente es algo muy sencillo y pese a estar en la misma carpeta, no encuentro el modo de no me salga ese error.

¿Alguna idea? Si hace falta que lo cree desde cero siguiendo vuestros pasos, también puedo hacerlo copiando el código, que me dicen que está bien.

Si necesitáis algo más...

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

`SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()` devuelve `null` en proyectos independientes (stand-alone) En su lugar usa:

- `SpreadsheetApp.open(file)`
- `SpreadsheetApp.openById(id)`
- `SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url)`

O bien, en lugar de usar una proyecto independiente crea uno vinculado a una hoja de cálculo. Una forma de hacerlos es desde el menú Extensiones de las hojas de cálculo de Google.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Rubén, siguiendo tu consejo lo conseguí cambiando esas dos variables por: 
....

  `var SS = SpreadsheetApp.openById("xxxxxxxxxx");
  var sheetRegistro = SS.getActiveSheet();`

No sé si es el mejor modo, pero por ahora funciona. Espero no haberlo hecho mal y que luego deje de funcionar :O
Te lo agradezco y me anoto tu respuesta para otra ocasión! 
Un saludo